# Javascript accordion with addEventListener doesn't work

Tags: addeventlistener, accordion

I have tried to write an accordion in pure Javascript. But it doesn't work as I expect. I want to open a tab I clicked and close the others at the same time. But it only opens the one and doesn't close the rest.
Can anyone explain to me why this code of accordion in Javascript doesn't work?

HTMl

```
<ul>
      <li>
        <h5>Title 1 <span>&#8594</span></h5>
        <p>
          1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
          eiusmod tempor ncididunt ut labore et doncididunt ut labore et
          doncididunt ut labore et doincididunt ut labore et dolore magna.
        </p>
      </li>

      <li>
        <h5>Title 2 <span>&#8594</span></h5>
        <p>
          2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
          eiusmod tempor ncididunt ut labore et doncididunt ut labore et
          doncididunt ut labore et doincididunt ut labore et dolore magna.
        </p>
      </li>
 </ul>
```

CSS

```
p{display: none;}
.active{display:block;}
```

Javascript

```
const h5 = document.querySelectorAll("h5");
h5.forEach((el) => el.addEventListener("click", handleClick, false));
function handleClick(e) {
  h5.forEach((el) => el.classList.remove("active"));
  e.target.classList.toggle("active");
}
```